# hiding view and showing soft keyboard

Tags: android, view, android-tabhost

I have a View (Tabhost) and I want to show it when I click a button, and when I show thw Tabhost I hide the softkeyboard, and if I Tab the same button, I want to show the softkeyboard and hid the Tabhost, my cod of On click is bellow, but it did not behave as I want.. can any body help!?

```
public void show_smily(View view) { // event habdler
    EditText composer = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.message_composer);
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(
            Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

    TabHost tabHost = (TabHost)findViewById(R.id.tabHost);
    if(!tabHost.isShown()) {
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(composer.getWindowToken(),0);
        tabHost.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    if(tabHost.isShown()) {
        tabHost.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        imm.showSoftInput(composer,0);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I forgot to put else before the second if, so, the first codition true, and then the second will be true, the application was execute the two blocks...

```
public void show_smily(View view) { // event habdler
EditText composer = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.message_composer);
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(
        Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

TabHost tabHost = (TabHost)findViewById(R.id.tabHost);
if(!tabHost.isShown()) {
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(composer.getWindowToken(),0);
    tabHost.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
else if(tabHost.isShown()) { // here was the problem
    tabHost.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    imm.showSoftInput(composer,0);

}
```

}